# ¿Por qué cambiar "usted" con "tú"?

Tags: modismos, formalidad, persona-gramatical, ustedeo

Trabajo con mexicanos que suelen cambiar el uso de verbos de la forma de "usted" a la de "tú" platicando entre sí, y al revés también.

¿Hay reglas del uso de "usted" que cambian con la situación y no con la persona a quien se dirige?

Comment: ¿Quieres decir que una persona está hablando con otra de *tú* y de pronto pasa a hablarle de *usted*, o viceversa, sin que haya ningún motivo aparente?

Comment: Creo que se requiere saber en dónde se encuentran en el mundo. La respuesta cambiaría dependiendo si son, por ejemplo, mexicanos viviendo en California, mexicanos viviendo en Texas, mexicanos de regiones distintas en México, mexicanos en CDMX, etc. Dentro del español mexicano, existen varios subdialectos.

Answer (score 5):

Sin conocer el contexto es difícil responder. *Usted* generalmente expresa respeto, formalidad o distanciamiento, comparado con *tú*, pero en algunos dialectos es al revés y se usa de manera familiar.

Si una persona está hablando con otra, en un determinado lugar y en una determinada situación, no es probable que se traten de *tú* en un momento dado y al momento siguiente pasen a tratarse de *usted*. Se me ocurren algunos ejemplos donde sí podría cambiar:

- Si el uso de *usted* es irónico o sarcástico o parte del tono de una broma. Por ejemplo, si uno de mis compañeros de trabajo dice algo que me suena formal o estirado, yo puedo responderle tratándolo de *usted* irónicamente. (No sé si esto pasa en el español de México; pasa seguido en Argentina.)
- Si las personas que hablan están en presencia de un tercero ante el cual hay que mostrarse formales. Por ejemplo, dos empleados de distinta jerarquía pueden conocerse y hablar familiarmente de *tú*, pero cuando llega el jefe de ambos, pasan a hablarse entre ellos de *usted*.
- En los lugares donde *usted* se usa como forma de intimidad especial, dos personas pueden hablar siempre de *tú*, pero en el momento de contar o confiarse algo muy íntimo, pasar por un momento al *usted*. (No sé si esto puede ocurrir en el español de México; en Argentina no usamos nunca el *usted* así.)

Comment: and if I'm taking to a person who's 20 years my seniour, but the context is informal? say, to my landlord

Comment: @nylypej There are no rules, really; it depends on too many things. But the question was about people who mixed *usted* and *tú* in the same conversation with the same other people.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que esas reglas no existen pero no podría asegurartelo. Lo que sí puedo es trasladarte esta definición que da el DLE de la palabra **usted**:

> [**usted**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bBhdfZ5)
>
> 3. pron. person. 3.ª pers. m. y f. pl. Forma que, en nominativo, en vocativo o precedida de preposición, designa, en Canarias, en parte de
> Andalucía y en América, a las personas a las que se dirige quien habla
> o escribe, **sin hacer distinción de familiaridad, respeto o cortesía**.
> Niños, hay merienda para ustedes en la cocina.

Es decir, **usted** (y la forma verbal asociada) se usan como tercera persona sin que por ello se pretenda mostrar cortesía y **sin que dependa de la situación concreta**. Como indica el DLE esto ocurre en Canarias, Andalucía (doy fe como andaluz) y en Hispanoamérica (incluyendo México).

Como me [señala @pablodf76](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/27816/por-qu%C3%A9-cambiar-usted-con-t%C3%BA/27817#comment47072_27817), la acepción que indico arriba se corresponde al plural **ustedes**.

Consultando el [Diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/) encontramos:

> [**usted**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=CsI7XXSi8x0AIcvNpie)
>
> i.    fórm. Gu, Ho, ES, Ni. Se usa como forma de tratamiento de respeto de una persona a un niño.
> ii.   Ho, ES. Se usa como forma de tratamiento de cariño y amor entre los esposos.

Comment: Fíjate que esto se refiere a *ustedes* ("pron. person. 3.ª pers. m. y f. **pl.**"), que en efecto es neutral en cuanto a formalidad en estos lugares.

Comment: @pablodf76 Tienes razón. Amplio con la acepción de "usted" (singular) del diccionario de americanismos.

Answer (score 0):

El uso de **USTED** y **TU** depende de cada país e incluso dentro de cada país depende de la región. Por ejemplo en Colombia: en Bogotá y zona de influencia es común dirigirse de **TU** de hombre a mujer y viceversa, de padres a hijos(as), de hijos a padres y de **USTED** de hombre a hombre, a los abuelos(as); en cambio en el departamento de Antioquia, Caldas, Quindío usan USTED para dirigirse a cualquiera incluso entre novios y esposos. En los departamento de la Costa Caribe es habitual usar **TU** para dirigirse a cualquier persona así no exista una relación de confianza o cercanía (que por cierto es muy molesto para la gente del interior de Colombia, pues se toma como abuso de confianza).

Comment: Situar el usted en zona paisa, existiendo el voseo no es lo habitual en Colombia... quizá debas viajar un poco por la zona y te das cuenta que te hablan de vos con facilidad (se alterna el usted como formalismo, el vos para informales y el tú para cercanos...)