# ¿Es en algún caso "usted" descortés o excesivamente cercano?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, dialectos, ustedeo

Leyendo [¿Por qué cambiar "usted" con "tú"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/27816/1674) y sus respuestas me ha surgido la duda de si en algún lugar el uso de *usted* puede tener connotaciones de excesiva confianza.

En España se usa *usted* como muestra de respeto o cortesía hacia alguien. Además, el DLE tiene como tercera acepción de [*usted*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=bBhdfZ5):

> Forma que, en nominativo, en vocativo o precedida de preposición, designa, en Canarias, en parte de Andalucía y en América, a las personas a las que se dirige quien habla o escribe, sin hacer distinción de familiaridad, respeto o cortesía.

Por tanto, su uso puede considerarse coloquial en muchos ámbitos hispanohablantes.

Dicho lo cual: ¿existe algún caso o lugar en que usar *usted* en lugar de *vos* o *tú* sea percibido como falta de respeto? No me refiero al caso de que una pareja en España que se habla cariñosamente y de repente se refieren como *usted* para mostrar distanciamiento.

Comment: Ojo: una respuesta diciendo _no_ es perfectamente válida. [Ya ocurrió en otras ocasiones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21031/1674) y también es extremadamente útil saberlo.

Answer (score 2):

Como uruguayo no se me ocurre ninguna situación en que usted sea demasiado coloquial, en general ocurre lo contrario.

Se me ocurre que hasta no hace mucho había gente que usaba usted indiscriminadamente para todo, como dice la entrada de la DRAE. Pero esto en Uruguay está cayendo en desuso (o ya cayó) y creo que nunca nadie fuera a interpretar usted como demasiado coloquial. Esta costumbre de tratar a todo el mundo de usted está asociada al modo de hablar del campo, donde las costumbres cambian con más lentitud, pero actualmente no conozco a nadie que hable así.

Ejemplo de uso de usted para todo es la historieta Inodoro Pereyra, donde se muestra de manera exagerada la vida del campo en Argentina.